# Can I Pull All Images on Facebook that I am tagged in with a particular person?

Tags: facebook, image

I am going to be using the Facebook SDK, however I was wondering if there was a way that I could use this SDK to pull a listing of all pictures I share with a certain person.  For instance, if it is Friend X's birthday today, I would like to pull a list of all images that me and Friend X are tagged in together.

Any advice would be helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could perform the following request
GET me/photos?type=tagged&fields=id,tags

this will return all your tagged photos , and a json array of people who are tagged in it , you could parse the json response and iterate over the tagged people to determine whether the friend you specify is tagged or not .

Navigate in your browser to the following URL to get an idea of what I'm talking about
https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos?type=tagged&fields=id,tags&access_token={Your Access Token}